# Broadcast Receiver to detect change in mobile network

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, network-state

I am looking for a way to make my Android app

**do something every time there is a change in mobile network**,

i.e. going from 2g to 3g, 4g to wifi etc.

All I can find for broadcast receivers are the ones that execute on loss or gain of network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)? The [LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE) and [LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE) flags look promising.