# Android 3g on off event

Tags: android, status, 3g

Is there any broadcast event when 3G been ON or OFF ?

For now I was trying to receive following event:

```
<receiver android:name="tw.com.xxx">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" /> <!-- for test -->
    <action android:name="android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED" /> <!-- Seems not 3G event -->
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Seems they aren't 3G event at all.

Which action should I receive to monitor 3G been turned ON/OFF ?

Any way to know if 3G been turned ON or OFF ?

Any suggestions are welcome :-)

Comment: Have a look at this very similar to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518719/broadcast-receiver-to-detect-change-in-mobile-network

Comment: Thanks for your tips, will feedback if I got working solution... :-)